# Bootstrap 4 - how to make scrollspy work without using nav or list-group?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, scrollspy

Is there a way to make scrollspy work without using `nav` or `list-group`?

Bootstrap documentation for scrollspy states that it may be used only on `nav` or `list group` components. [DOCUMENTATION](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/scrollspy/)

> ### How it works
>
> Scrollspy has a few requirements to function properly:
>
> - If you’re building our JavaScript from source, it requires util.js.
> - It must be used on a Bootstrap nav component or list group.
> - Scrollspy requires `position: relative;` on the element you’re spying on, usually the `<body>`.
> - When spying on elements other than the `<body>`, be sure to have a `height` set and `overflow-y: scroll;` applied.
> - Anchors (`<a>`) are required and must point to an element with that id.

---

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41904571/scrollspy-effect-on-div-only) is similar, but for Bootstrap 3 (not 4) and the answer is to add `role="tablist"`. Well, it doesn't work here. There are many questions on SO about scrollspy, but mostly for Bootstrap 3.

#### CODE:

```css
/*DEMO*/
nav{top:50%;left:1.5rem;transform:translateY(-50%)}
nav a{display:block;width:20px;height:20px;margin-bottom:.5rem}

/*COLORS*/
nav a{background:black}
nav a.active{background:red}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#nav" data-offset="0">

<section class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="item-1" class="col-12 vh-100 bg-primary"></div>
        <div id="item-2" class="col-12 vh-100 bg-warning"></div>
        <div id="item-3" class="col-12 vh-100 bg-danger"></div>
        <div id="item-4" class="col-12 vh-100 bg-success"></div>
        <div id="item-5" class="col-12 vh-100 bg-info"></div>
    </div>
</section>

<nav id="nav" class="d-flex flex-column position-fixed">
    <a href="#item-1"></a>
    <a href="#item-2"></a>
    <a href="#item-3"></a>
    <a href="#item-4"></a>
    <a href="#item-5"></a>
</nav>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overcome this by using the required class `list-group-item` and reset the CSS like you want:

```css
/*DEMO*/

nav {
  top: 50%;
  left: 1.5rem;
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}

#nav a {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}


/*COLORS*/

#nav a {
  background: black
}

#nav a.active {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#nav" data-offset="0">

  <section class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="item-1" class="col-12 vh-100 bg-primary"></div>
      <div id="item-2" class="col-12 vh-100 bg-warning"></div>
      <div id="item-3" class="col-12 vh-100 bg-danger"></div>
      <div id="item-4" class="col-12 vh-100 bg-success"></div>
      <div id="item-5" class="col-12 vh-100 bg-info"></div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <nav id="nav" class="d-flex flex-column position-fixed">
    <a href="#item-1" class="list-group-item"></a>
    <a href="#item-2" class="list-group-item"></a>
    <a href="#item-3" class="list-group-item"></a>
    <a href="#item-4" class="list-group-item"></a>
    <a href="#item-5" class="list-group-item"></a>
  </nav>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It would be better to find a solution without adding `list-group-item`, but I think this is the easiest one and it works nicely. I forgot to reset all the style and that was the problem. `d-flex flex-column` can be replaced with `list-group` and `display: block;` can be removed when used with `list-group item` because it's already in bootstrap. :)